# background-image with tr and th

Tags: css

I have 'tr' with background-image and on 'th' I want to show a image on its right corner to indiect if this column is sorted. I have css style like following:

tr.header {

```
background-image: url(../Images/bg.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

}

th.sort {

```
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center right; 
background-image: url(../Images/sort_bg.gif);
```

}

This works well on IE8 and firefox3, but not on IE7.

Anyone has any idea of how to make it working on IE7?

Comment: screenshot...or a link?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this doctype to the top of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

are both classes not working or just one of the classes not working?

.header { background: url(../Images/bg.gif) repeat-x; }
.sort { background: url(../Images/sort_bg.gif) no-repeat right; } /* should default to middle */

...

Comment: By not working on IE7 I mean: I want sort_bg.gif sit on top of bg.gif. but on IE7, bg.gif is replaced by sort_bg.gif, in another word, my tr has lost its background image.

Answer (score 0):

This is way old, however it comes up at the top of google when you search for 'th background image css', so it's worth getting an answer in here.

I think you are out of luck with multiple bg images on a single element in IE7:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

"Note: IE8 and earlier do not support multiple background images on one element."

not sure why it was workng for you in IE8 at all.

If I actually come up with a solution I'll post it.